# Append string at end of previous change log details in SP

Tags: c#, sql, regex

I am trying to add change log details using C# and regex. In the below given code we need to add change log details after the latest changelog details. I have tried using regex but was only able to match the header of the change log. Below is a sample script from stored procedure, we are trying to use the same code for SP's, Triggers and Functions as well. Please let me know if there would be any limitations when using regex for other object types.

Regex used to match the changelog header: ((?i)DATE\s*(?i)AUTHOR\s*(?i)DESCRIPTION\s*)

Input:

```
/***********************************************************************************************      
PROCEDURE:  DEL_ABCD_Table1     
      
PARAMETERS: Sample int
      
APPLICATION:    ABCD

PURPOSE:    Deletes all records from the Table1

NOTES:  

MODIFIED 
DATE        AUTHOR      DESCRIPTION
----------  --------------  -------------------------------------------------------------
08/08/2012  Jim         Initial Version
09/25/2014  Pam         Adding Canvas
09/11/2018  Dwight      Adding rootbeer 
12/24/2019  Angela      Adding Catnip
**********************************************************************************************/
```

Expected Output:

```
/***********************************************************************************************      
PROCEDURE:  DEL_ABCD_Table1     
      
PARAMETERS: Sample int
      
APPLICATION:    ABCD

PURPOSE:    Deletes all records from the Table1

NOTES:  

MODIFIED 
DATE        AUTHOR      DESCRIPTION
----------  --------------  -------------------------------------------------------------
08/08/2012  Jim         Initial Version
09/25/2014  Pam         Adding Canvas
09/11/2018  Dwight      Adding rootbeer 
12/24/2019  Angela      Adding Catnip
11/01/2019  SK          Adding Thats what she said
**********************************************************************************************/
```

https://regex101.com/r/w351JF/1

Comment: Do you need regex to appending to a file? Not sure I understand what you're asking. You can read the file, then insert a line just before the last line and rewrite it.

Comment: Please include the regex you tried also here in the question, not only as external link.

Comment: @RufusL : I was able to read the file and rewrite it , but inserting the new changelog details exactly before the last entry is my problem.

Comment: change log in source header. yuck! That's what source code control is for. Might have been common 20 years ago, but it's an anti-pattern now.

Comment: You could look for the first line starting with "****"

Comment: Why not just find the last line and insert your line before that? `^\*+\/\s+$` should work (your line has extra spaces after `*/`).

Comment: Imho there is nothing unclear about this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match until after the last change log:

```
(?i)DATE\s+AUTHOR\s+DESCRIPTION\r?\n--[\s-]+\r?\n(?:(?!\*\*).*\r?\n)*(?=\*\*)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?i)` Use a case insensitive match
- `DATE\s+AUTHOR\s+DESCRIPTION\r?\n` Match the change log header
- `--[\s-]+\r?\n` Match for example at least `--` followed by 1+ times a `-` or whitespace char
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?!\*\*).*\r?\n` Match the whole line if it does not start with `**`
- `)*` Close the group and repeat it 0+ times to match all the lines
- `(?=\*\*)` Assert for example at least `**` for the last line

If the values are separeted by only tabs, you can use `\t+` instead of `\s+`

[.NET Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fi%29DATE%5cs%2bAUTHOR%5cs%2bDESCRIPTION%5cr%3f%5cn--%5b%5cs-%5d%2b%5cr%3f%5cn%28%3f%3a%28%3f!%5c*%5c*%29.*%5cr%3f%5cn%29*%28%3f%3d%5c*%5c*%29&i=%2f***********************************************************************************************++++++%0d%0aPROCEDURE%3a++DEL_ABCD_Table1+++++%0d%0a++++++%0d%0aPARAMETERS%3a+Sample+int%0d%0a++++++%0d%0aAPPLICATION%3a%09ABCD%0d%0a%0d%0aPURPOSE%3a%09Deletes+all+records+from+the+Table1%0d%0a%0d%0aNOTES%3a%09%0d%0a%0d%0aMODIFIED+%0d%0aDATE%09%09AUTHOR%09%09DESCRIPTION%0d%0a----------%09--------------%09-------------------------------------------------------------%0d%0a08%2f08%2f2012%09Jim%09Initial+Version%0d%0a09%2f25%2f2014%09Pam%09Adding+Canvas%0d%0a09%2f11%2f2018%09Dwight%09Adding+rootbeer+%0d%0a12%2f24%2f2019%09Angela%09Adding+Catnip%0d%0a**********************************************************************************************%2f++++++&r=%24%26011%2f01%2f2019++SK++++++++++Adding+Thats+what+she+said%0d%0a)

Replace with the full match followed by your replacement string and a newline.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, only addition I have done is that I've put braces to form groups for easy replacement. Thank you